# How much of a role does authorial intent play in modern academic literary analysis?

Tags: theory

In [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/817/how-can-we-draw-meaning-from-works-if-it-was-not-intended-by-the-author?noredirect=1#comment1216_817), I asked about how meaning gets into a work if not intended by the author. In researching that question, I ran across mention of "authorial intent". In reading about it, I learned that it went through phases of being very important to analysists and other phases where it did not matter at all. In modern academic literary analysis, how much of a role does it play? Is it only to backup previously made claims or does it ever form the center of fundamental arguments?

Comment: I think I'm actually going to have to VTC as too broad. "Modern" academic literary analysis is extremely broad and vague, and while the surface level answer is "it matters," no answer could really be comprehensively complete without a thorough discussion of all predominant modern literary perspectives. If the question were edited from a very generic "how much of a role?" to a more specific "does it matter to [a specific line of thought]?", then the question would become answerable again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a dupe of an unanswered question.

Comment: If @Emrakul improves his answer, could we reopen this?

Comment: Reopen and close as dupe

Comment: @Emrakul Maybe you could post your now-deleted answer from below on the (now reopened) dupe target instead?

Comment: @rand Possibly, but I'm not sure it has enough references to be worth copying over.

Comment: @Skooba We can't do that because the other doesn't have a good answer.